# Developing service in .NET Framework 4, Error 1053

Tags: .net, windows-services, .net-framework-version

So I'm trying to run a service I programmed and for some reason it's giving me this error when try I start it:

```
Error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
```

My code is pretty basic.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new Program() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string SourceName = "WindowsService.ExceptionLog";
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(SourceName))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(SourceName, "Application");
            }

            EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
            eventLog.Source = SourceName;
            string message = string.Format("Exception: {0} \n\nStack: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            eventLog.WriteEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }

    public Program()
    {
        this.ServiceName = "FetchFeed";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);

        //TODO: place your start code here
    repeat: FetchFeed();
        Thread.Sleep(3600000);
        goto repeat;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();

        //TODO: clean up any variables and stop any threads
    }

private static void FetchFeed()
{
    //Some HTTP requests and retrieval.
}
```

and this is the Installer Class:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class Service_Installer : Installer
{
    public Service_Installer()
    {
        ServiceProcessInstaller processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

        //set the privileges
        processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

        serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "FetchFeed";
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual;

        //must be the same as what was set in Program's constructor
        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "FetchFeed";

        this.Installers.Add(processInstaller);
        this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
    }
}
```

What could be the the reason behind the error? I have checked the FetchFeed() to be working as a standalone application with no Exceptions.

Comment: You have to start a Thread http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx  in your onStart instead of sleeping

Comment: The thing is I have to run the thread in every 1hour, how can I do that without putting the main process to sleep, because using a Timer would use more resources and would not be efficient, how to tell the service you have to run the thread in every 1hour? @rene

Comment: Is that a `goto`??!! This is c#, use a while loop.

Comment: Is the server already under that much stress that you cann't have antoher Timer in memory?

Comment: You could try a simpler solution: a commandline application that gets called by the Windows Task Scheduler

Comment: @rene I read an article saying Timers should not be used in Services, if you think otherwise, please do shed some light.

Comment: @DerpyDerp Can you point to that article?  My guess is that it is wrong.

Comment: @rene I do not want to go that way, Windows Task Scheduler is not an option here. :(

Comment: @rene I'm searching for the article, while I do that, can you please tell me how I can implement Timers in this case, efficiently?

Comment: @cadrell0, I'm searching for the article.

Comment: @cadrell0, here you go, http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/10/24/428303.aspx

Comment: @DerpyDerp The important line from this article is the following "A Windows Service is the wrong solution to scheduling one-off custom processes. The right solution for scheduling simple processes is the Windows Task Scheduler."  rene suggested doing this, but you said you could not.  Being that you cannot do the recommended solution from the article, you have no choice but to use a Timer.

Comment: "you have no choice but to use a Timer" - @cadrell0. sadly, true.

Comment: The sad part is you cannot solve this problem the correct way, which is a Scheduled task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the appopiate [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer)

```
public class YourService
{
       var tim = new System.Timers.Timer(60 * 60 * 1000); // 1 hour

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)  
    {  
        base.OnStart(args);  

        tim.AutoReset = true;
        tim.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(tim_Elapsed);
        tim.Enabled = true;
        // first time run
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback(FetchFeed));
    }

    static void tim_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
          FetchFeed();
    }
}
```

Comment: so how to make sure that the FetchFeed() runs for the first time without waiting for 1hour? @rene

Comment: If FetchFeed stays guaranteed under 30 seconds you could cal it immediately. You can have a second timer that just runs after a second with autoreset = false or use the ThreadPool to queue a workitem. I did the last option in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
repeat: FetchFeed();
Thread.Sleep(3600000);
goto repeat;
```

This is your problem right here.
A Windows Service should respond within 30 seconds, so Windows knows is has successfully started.

With this code you are blocking the only thread and the service doesn't respond to anything anymore.

Try doing this on a different thread or another way.

I would suggest another way, because using a `goto` is a real no-go :)

Also check out some tutorials and basic documentation on Windows Service to get a better understanding.